# What is causing unable to prepare context: path "./springboot" not found?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, docker

I'm a bit new but I am trying to create a Docker compose which runs an Angular, MySQL and Springboot project. Right now I can't create the angular and spring boot because in both Linux sent me this

> "[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
> unable to prepare context: path "./springboot" not found"

This is my docker file:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
 nginx:
  container_name: nginx
  image: nginx:1.13
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 80:80
   - 443:443
  volumes:
  - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d

 angular:
  container_name: angular
  restart: always
  build: angular
  depends_on:
   - app
  ports:
   - "4200:4200"

 mysql:
  container_name: mysql
  image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
  environment:
   MYSQL_DATABASE: test
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: formation123
   MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
  ports:
   - 3306:3306
  restart: always

 springboot:
  restart: always
  build:
   context: ./springboot
   dockerfile: .docker/app/dockerfile
  working_dir: /springboot
  volumes:
   - ./springboot:/springboot
   - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
  expose:
   - "8080"
  depends_on:
   - nginx
   - mysql
  command: mvn clean spring-boot:run -dspring-boot.run.profiles=docker
```

I managed to create the image of MySQL and nginx but can't launch the Angular and Springboot

Comment: I'd expect that error to mean exactly what it says: there is not a `springboot` subdirectory under the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: So where i should run the docker-compose.yml? In both of my projects? Or do i need to search or create the springboot and angular directorys? Sorry for being a bit lost in this.

Comment: As you've shown this file, it should be located in a directory with `springboot` and `angular` subdirectories.  The `build:` context directories are resolved relative to the Compose file's location.